# How to reset multiprocessing dictionary variable back to default state

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using `multiprocessing` module a "special" kind of dictionary variable `poolDict` is declared. It is used to write-to by every `multiprocessing` process started. From the same `poolDict` dictionary the main function is able to read the data. 
The question: After all the processes are finished how to reset the `poolDict` to an empty dictionary to its default state? The variable keeps "remembering" all the data written to it by the processes.

#### Code was edited later to illustrate a `poolDict` usage clearer (as well to show how I am using `while` loop to read a progress values from `poolDict` in "real-time").

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
poolDict=mp.Manager().dict()

def myFunct(arg):
    print 'myFunct():', arg
    for i in range(110):
        for n in range(500000):
            pass
        poolDict[arg]=i
    print 'myFunct(): completed', arg, poolDict


from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=2)
myArgsList=['arg1','arg2','arg3']
pool.map_async( myFunct, myArgsList)


def printMessage(arg):
    print '\t The message is:', arg

state=True
while state:
    if not poolDict:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        continue

    printMessage(poolDict)

    check=True
    if len(poolDict.keys())<len(myArgsList):                
        check=False

    for value in poolDict.values():
        if value<105:
            check=False
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print '\n\t\t\t ...SETTING check to', check, 'since one of the values is <105', value
            break           

    if check:
        state=False
        print '\n\t\t\t\t\t YAHOO!!!!', check, 'len(poolDict.keys())<len(myArgsList):',len(poolDict.keys()), 'vs', len(myArgsList), 'and  not a single value is less than 150:', poolDict.values()
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `poolDict.clear()` to empty the dict. I'm not having any issues seeing the prints show up when I run this code from a command prompt on Linux. How are you executing your script?

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited the code a bit to make poolDict variable more meaningful for this example. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: After your edit, all the prints show up without me making any changes. How are you executing your script?

Comment: After I span the multi-processes `poolDict` is used to update "main" function with the progresses of the processes running. This progress information is used by "main" function to feed GUI based PyQt QProgressBars in real-time.

Comment: @Sputnix I mean how are you actually running this test program? command prompt, IDLE, something else? You mentioned that none of that `myFunct` doesn't print anything when you run the script, but it's printing just fine for me running it from a bash prompt.

Comment: I've just started a new post dedicated to a printing issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961316/why-function-called-by-multiprocessing-is-not-printing-the-messages