# Why function called by multiprocessing is not printing the messages?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Why in the example below myFunct() is not printing any messages is supposed to when it is ran by 'multiprocessing'? And how to solve it?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
poolDict=mp.Manager().dict()

def myFunct(arg):
    print 'myFunct():', arg
    for i in range(110):
        for n in range(500000):
            pass
        poolDict[arg]=i
    print 'myFunct(): completed', arg, poolDict


from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=2)
myArgsList=['arg1','arg2','arg3']

pool.map_async( myFunct, myArgsList)
print 'completed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't printing because the main process is exiting immediately after calling `map_async`, so none of the child processes have a chance to actually run. It prints as expected if you make the script wait for the children to finish:

```
pool.map_async( myFunct, myArgsList)
pool.close()
pool.join()
print 'completed'
```

Output from bash prompt:

```
dan@dan:~> ./mult.py 
myFunct(): arg1
myFunct(): arg2
myFunct(): completed arg2 {'arg1': 108, 'arg2': 109}
myFunct(): arg3
myFunct(): completed arg1 {'arg1': 109, 'arg2': 109}
myFunct(): completed arg3 {'arg1': 109, 'arg2': 109, 'arg3': 109}
completed
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you use apply_async() instead of map_async() and add the close() and join() calls:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
poolDict=mp.Manager().dict()

def myFunct(arg):
    print 'myFunct():', arg
    for i in range(110):
        for n in range(500000):
            pass
        poolDict[arg]=i
    print 'myFunct(): completed', arg, poolDict

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=2)
myArgsList=['arg1','arg2','arg3']

pool.apply_async( myFunct, myArgsList)
pool.close()
pool.join()
print 'completed'
```

Result:

```
myFunct(): arg1
myFunct(): arg2
myFunct(): completedmyFunct(): completed arg1 {'arg1': 109, 'arg2': 109}
 arg2 {'arg1': 108, 'arg2': 109}
myFunct(): arg3
myFunct(): completed arg3 {'arg1': 109, 'arg2': 109, 'arg3': 109}
completed
```

Comment: `apply_async` is doing something very different from `map_async`. The two calls are not interchangeable. `apply_async` calls `myFunct(myArgsList)` in a subprocess. `map_async` calls `myFunct(i)` in a subprocess, for each `i` in `MyArgsList`